# Library/ functions from TAH.h - There is no response in my code

Tags: c++, arduino, shared-libraries, arduino-ide

```
#include <Mouse.h>
#include <Keyboard.h>
#include <IRLib.h>
#include <IRLibMatch.h>
#include <IRLibRData.h>
#include <IRLibTimer.h>
#include <TAH.h>

TAH myTAH;

int mode, joyX, joyY, dPad, Buttonpadtag;

char val;          // Store Value of Buttonpadtag
char mem = ' ';    // Store Value of Buttonpadtag till getting new Value


void setup() 
{
    Keyboard.begin();
    Mouse.begin();
    Keyboard.releaseAll();  

    Serial.begin(9600);
    myTAH.begin(9600);

    myTAH.enterCommandMode();

    myTAH.setName("Play");
    myTAH.setWorkRole(SLAVE);
    myTAH.setAuth(OPEN);
    myTAH.setWorkMode(REMOTE_CONTROL);
    myTAH.setiBeaconMode(ON);

    myTAH.exitCommandMode();
}

void loop() 
{
    // if there's any serial available, read it:
    if (myTAH.available()) 
    {
        ///// Parsing Value From Left Controller

        mode = myTAH.parseInt();

        joyX = myTAH.parseInt(); 

        joyY = myTAH.parseInt();

        dPad = myTAH.parseInt();   

        Buttonpadtag = myTAH.parseInt();

        // joystick value mapping
        joyX = map(joyX, -128,128, 0, 255);
        joyY = map(joyY, 128, -128, 0, 255);

        // look for the newline. That's the end of your
        // sentence:
        if (myTAH.read() == 'P') 
        {
            if(mode == 0) // App is in PS mode
            {
                // Always be getting fresh data
                dataForController_t SonycontrollerData = SonygetControllerData();
                // Then send out the data over the USB connection
                // Joystick.set(controllerData) also works.
                Joystick.setControllerData(SonycontrollerData);
            }
            else if(mode == 1) // App is in Computer Joystick Mode
            {
                /////////  Button Pad mapped to User Defined Computer Keys  ////////////
                if(Buttonpadtag >> 0  && Buttonpadtag != 5 && Buttonpadtag != 6)
                { 
                    val = Buttonpadtag;
                    mem = val;
                    Keyboard.press(val);

                }
                else
                {
                    val = mem;
                    Keyboard.release(val);
                }

                if(Buttonpadtag == 5)
                {
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_ESC);
                }
                else
                {
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_ESC);
                }

                if(Buttonpadtag == 6)
                {
                    Mouse.press(MOUSE_LEFT);
                }
                else
                {
                    Mouse.release(MOUSE_LEFT);
                }

                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                /////////  dPad mapped to Computer Arrow Keys  ////////////

                if(dPad == 2 )
                {
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_UP_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
                }

                if(dPad == 8 )
                {
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_UP_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
                }

                if(dPad == 6 )
                {
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_UP_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
                }

                if(dPad == 4 )
                {
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_UP_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);
                }

                if(dPad == 3 )
                {
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_UP_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
                }

                if(dPad == 9 )
                {
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_UP_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
                }

                if(dPad == 7 )
                {
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_UP_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);

                }

                if(dPad == 1 )
                {
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_UP_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);
                }

                if(dPad == 5)
                {
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_UP_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_DOWN_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_RIGHT_ARROW);
                    Keyboard.release(KEY_LEFT_ARROW);
                }

                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            }

            //print the three numbers in one string as hexadecimal:
            Serial.print(mode, DEC);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print(joyX, DEC);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print(joyY, DEC);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.print(dPad, DEC);
            Serial.print(",");
            Serial.println(Buttonpadtag, DEC);

            Serial.flush(); 
        }
    }
}
```

> I went after this code on Git, then set things up to work as prescribed,  It gives the broken callback function in compiler an error (`dataForController_t`) to a memory allocation that is pre designated for other data. The slashed text comments should explain it better, left there by the developer. Although my community resources are far from many, I'm a work in progress when it comes to coding. Although I need more help than I can give, I don't think I'm ready to code a book.

From other code examples of function and methods in this sketch, I added a period between the two functions to see if I could have a hand in it. No alternative results given.

```
///////////// Play Station Data Structure /////////////
```

Originally written as `dataForController_t SonygetControllerData(void)`
the error is from syntax given: dataForController_t SonygetControllerData(void)
after the "error" 'dataForController_t' does not name a type

when the in-between period inserted as shown, same error persistent. Have not tried anything more.

```
dataForController_t.SonygetControllerData(void)
{  
    // Set up a place for our controller data
    //  Use the getBlankDataForController() function, since
    //  just declaring a fresh dataForController_t tends
    //  to get you one filled with junk from other, random
    //  values that were in those memory locations before

    dataForController_t controllerData = getBlankDataForController();

    // Since our buttons are all held high and
    //  pulled low when pressed, we use the "!"
    //  operator to invert the readings from the pins

    if(Buttonpadtag == 1)
    {
        controllerData.crossOn = 1;
        Serial.println(" Cross");
    }
    else if(Buttonpadtag == 2)
    {
        controllerData.circleOn = 1;
        Serial.println(" Circle");
    }
    else if(Buttonpadtag == 3)
    {
        controllerData.squareOn = 1;
        Serial.println(" Square");
    }
    else if(Buttonpadtag == 4 )
    {
        controllerData.triangleOn = 1;
        Serial.println(" Triangle");
    }
    else if(Buttonpadtag == 7 )
    {
        controllerData.selectOn = 1;
        Serial.println(" Select");
    }
    else if(Buttonpadtag == 8 )
    {
        controllerData.startOn = 1;
        Serial.println(" Start");
    }

    // Set the analog sticks

    controllerData.leftStickX = joyX;
    controllerData.leftStickY = joyY;

    // And return the data!
    return controllerData;
}
```

Comment: dataForController_t.SonygetControllerData(void) {     Take that period out of there for starters.

Comment: That period definitely doesn't belong.  Randomly adding syntax is almost never the problem.  If you don't know what that period is for, then learn that before you start sticking them in random places.  If it says that doesn't name a type then it means you can't use it as a type.  Probably something isn't being included right or you've got a bad version of a library somewhere and that type definition is missing.

Comment: Post the complete actual error message from before you started changing things.

Comment: ResolveLibrary(HID.h)
ResolveLibrary(Keyboard.h)
IRLib.h: fatal error: IRLib.h: No such file or directory
RAW!!

Answer (score 0):

The lib you are using is an incomplete version (and WIP). First copy the original library [from here](https://github.com/tah-io/Tah_Arduino_Library) there you'll find the missing IRxx.libs. Then you have to define the dataForController_t struct yourself so define in [this example program PS3](https://github.com/dvdnhm/sketches/blob/master/examples/SonyPS3/SonyPS3.ino):

```
int16_t LeftjoyX;
int16_t LeftjoyY;
int16_t RightjoyX;
int16_t RightjoyY;
int16_t Buttonpadtag;

struct  dataForController_t {
  int16_t leftStickX;
  int16_t leftStickY;
  int16_t rightStickX;
  int16_t rightStickY;
  bool  dpadRightOn;
  bool dpadLeftOn;
  bool dpadUpOn;
  bool dpadDownOn;
  bool triangleOn;
  bool squareOn;
  bool circleOn;
  bool crossOn;
  bool l1On;
  bool l2On;
  bool r1On;
  bool r2On;
  bool selectOn;
 bool startOn ;
 bool homeOn ;
} controllerData;
```

comment out the line

//Joystick.setControllerData(SonycontrollerData)
and add the function

```
dataForController_t  getBlankDataForController() {
  // Has to be written WIP - JUST DUMMY DATA
  controllerData.leftStickX = 0;
  controllerData.leftStickY = 0;
  controllerData.rightStickX = 0;
  controllerData.rightStickY = 0;
  // And return the data!
  return controllerData;
}
```

The last one has to be filled with all variables from the defined struct and set them to 0.
 Than the demo compiles. I doubt that it will work properly as [the lib](https://github.com/tah-io/Tah_Arduino_Library/) is a half finished effort left to the public 2015. So either finish it yourself or forget about using it.

Comment: I'll just post it for hire else where. Thanks!